# Deploying ember application on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

I am facing this issue while deploying ember application on Heroku. ember build is working in my local. I tried clearing npm and bower cache also but still no luck.

```
    ember-cli : 2.9.1
    node : 6.10.1
    npm : 3.10.10
    bower : 1.8.0
```

**git push heroku master**

```
remote: DEPRECATION: Overriding init without calling this._super is deprecated. Please call `this._super.init && this._super.init.apply(this, arguments);` addon: `ember-cli-htmlbars`
remote:     at Function.Addon.lookup (/tmp/build_f0a1863f911e012b791218614939ef87/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:1005:27)
remote: WARNING: Node v7.9.0 has currently not been tested against Ember CLI and may result in unexpected behaviour.
remote: Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
remote: Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
remote: cleaning up...
remote: Build failed.
remote: File: assets/vendor.css
remote: The Broccoli Plugin: [broccoli-persistent-filter:CleanCSSFilter] failed with:
    remote: Error: Broken @import declaration of "theme.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "accordion.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "autocomplete.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "button.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "datepicker.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "dialog.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "draggable.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "menu.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "progressbar.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "resizable.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "selectable.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "selectmenu.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "sortable.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "slider.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "spinner.css"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "tabs.csError running: ember build --environment production 2>&1
    remote: s"
    remote: Broken @import declaration of "tooltip.css"
    remote:     at arrayToError (/tmp/build_f0a1863f911e012b791218614939ef87/node_modules/array-to-error/index.js:45:15)
    remote:     at minifyCallback (/tmp/build_f0a1863f911e012b791218614939ef87/node_modules/clean-css-promise/index.js:33:20)
    remote:     at module.exports (/tmp/build_f0a1863f911e012b791218614939ef87/ember-cli-build.js:23:14)
    remote:     at Class.setupBroccoliBuilder (/tmp/build_f0a1863f911e012b791218614939ef87/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:70:19)
    remote: 
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Failed trying to compile heroku/ember-cli-deploy
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile emberjs app.
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push failed
```

Comment: did you try using node 7.9 on your local and tried running a production build?

Comment: Got solution for this:

Answer (score 1):

```
ember install ember-cli-jquery-ui
```

In ember-cli-build.js add the below lines:

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  minifyCSS: {
    options: {
      processImport: false
    }
  }
});
```

```
ember build --environment production
```

Comment: Can you please explain ?

Comment: @rjdkolb Please check this : https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-preprocessor-registry/issues/8